# No component factory found for MechanicDataCollectionComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am getting this error

> No component factory found for MechanicDataCollectionComponent. Did
> you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

I have even added MechanicDataCollectionComponent into the entrypoint but still getting the error.

Below is my admin-layout.module.ts

```
import {
  MatButtonModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatRippleModule,
  MatFormFieldModule,
  MatTooltipModule,
  MatSelectModule,
  MatTabsModule, MatTableModule, MatPaginatorModule, MatCheckboxModule,
} from '@angular/material';
import { MechanicDataCollectionComponent } from './mechanic-data-collection/mechanic-data-collection.component';
import { MatDialogModule } from "@angular/material/dialog";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatButtonModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatDialogModule,
  ],

  declarations: [   
    MechanicDataCollectionComponent,
  ],
  entryComponents: [MechanicDataCollectionComponent],
})
export class AdminLayoutModule {}
```

Below is the admin-layout.component.ts

```
 openDialog() {
      const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MechanicDataCollectionComponent);

      dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
        console.log(`Dialog result: ${result}`);
      });
    }
```

What would be the reason for this error? Below is the file structure

[image: File structure]

Comment: Could you please add this component to your app.module.ts file?

Comment: @Muthupriya as an entrypoint or declarations?

Answer (score 0):

Your component AdminLayoutComponent doesn't belong to AdminLayoutModule. You should add it into the declarations array.